# Use preg_match_all from form post submission url

Tags: php, preg-match-all, form-post

I have been using `preg_match_all` from URL's where we can fetch data using `GET` method, but how do I get data using `POST` method.
In my case, I want to fetch PNR details from http://www.indianrail.gov.in/pnr_Enq.html (which is a form that posts data) and fetch all required details. I know form post using `jQuery` but how do I go about using `preg_match_all` in PHP?

Comment: extend your question with input data and the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP does this for you and presents you all variables available from HTTP request in the form of *superglobals*: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

In your case there's `$_POST` superglobal array which contains all variables parsed from current HTTP `POST` request: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST`

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Also, you don't need to regex match your url, there's also a `$_GET` superglobal